# Changing Windows 10 Accent Color via GPO

Tags: windows-10, colors, group-policy

I'd like to set a default accent color by using a group policy and have found that it is not affecting all aspects of Windows. I entered in my hex values (with the #) through Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Template > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific background and accent color, and ensured that they meet the 2:1 contrast ratio.
After manually forcing a gpupdate on computers within this scope, I can see that the colors only appear the the window popup that says "You're about to be signed out, Windows will shut down in less than a minute". I would like the accent color to apply in the Start Menu, taskbar, etc. just like if you manually change the accent color in Settings.
We are running Windows 10 Enterprise. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there perhaps a conflicting registry entry that's set?

Comment: @SamForbis looks like there may be, although manually changing "AccentColor" in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM and restarting does not change the accent color. Perhaps this is the wrong registry to change?